# Excel Powerquery - Get data from Model

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Very simply...
- I created a query using Excel PowerQuery and loading data ONLY as connection, not in a Sheet, and adding to Datamodel.

I would like now via VBA to query the data, selecting a value in the model with a simple WHERE clause.

I tried using `ActiveWorkbook.Connections` and so on, unsuccessfully (references to Activex Data Object is set). What should be the way? This is the code I am testing:

```
Public Sub SelectPQData()
Dim conn As Connection
Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet

On Error GoTo MyFail

Set conn = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(1).ModelConnection
```

error is application or model defined...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this to set the connection...

```
Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
Dim cn As WorkbookConnection

For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    If cn.Name = "ThisWorkbookDataModel" Then
        Set conn = cn
        Exit For
    End If
Next cn
```

OR simply this..

```
Set Conn = ThisWorkbook.Connections("ThisWorkbookDataModel")
```